# Creating pdfium dll

Tags: dll, pdfium

I am trying to create a dll for `pdfium` using Visual Studio 2013 (as in [Creating a dll in pdfium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236148/creating-a-dll-in-pdfium)) except that when I download `pdfium` project I set `DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0`, because now, by default, they use toolchain from depot_tools .

But I still get an error during the build process:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FPDF_BStr_Init referenced in function "public: class CFX_WideString __thiscall CPDFDoc_Environment::FFI_PostRequestURL(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (?FFI_PostRequestURL@CPDFDoc_Environment@@QAE?AVCFX_WideString@@PB_W0000@Z)    ..\pdfium\fpdfxfa.lib(fpdfxfa_app.obj)  pdfium`

and similar about `_FPDF_BStr_Clear`

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FPDF_BStr_Clear referenced in function "public: class CFX_WideString __thiscall CPDFDoc_Environment::FFI_PostRequestURL( ...`

I through, that it may be problem with xfa, so I tried to build pdfium without it. I removed `PDF_ENABLE_XFA` from preprocessor definitions of all projects in this solution, but then i found that fxcodec and fxcrt dont build without that definition.
When I leave that definitions for that projects i can successfully build pdfium project, but when i use it in my app, it fails.

Then I tried to do it in different order and got dll, but without using of FPDFSDK_EXPORTS definition. When I add it, those errors appear.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to edit the build commands to disable XFA. When you run `gn args out/Debug` you can add a `pdf_enable_xfa=false` entry. You can also disable V8 with `pdf_enable_v8=false`.

There was recently an option added to build a complete library for PDFium (not tested with V8 or XFA yet). If you add `pdf_is_complete_lib=true` and build you should just have to link against the libpdfium that is generated.